# IIS maxBandwidth don't limit upload

Tags: iis, upload, web-config, limit, bandwidth

i want to limit upload and download in IIS. i set `maxBandwidth` to 2000. this limit work for download correctly. but when upload file this limit don't work.

so how can i limit upload bandwidth in IIS?

**Note**

in my web.config file i set:

```
<system.web>
    <httpRuntime maxRequestLength="2147483647" executionTimeout="3600" />
</system.web>
<system.webserver>
    <security>
        <requestFiltering>
            <requestLimits maxAllowedContentLength="4249967295" />
        </requestFiltering>
    </security>
</system.webserver>
```

when i remove this line upload is limited but when add this lines uploud bandwidth is unlimited.

Answer (score 0):

This is by design, the `maxBandwidth` setting is for download only.

IIS doesn't support any bandwith restrictions for uploads.

`maxRequestLength` and `maxAllowedContentLength` have nothing to do with bandwidth, they apply to the maximum total size of a request.

Comment: thank you for your reply. but when i set "maxBandwidth" and remove that lines, IIS limit upload bandwidth to something i set.